# Tensorflow - hello world program, prepends b to output

Tags: python, tensorflow

After installing tensorflow and running the short program following instructions at [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#run_a_short_tensorflow_program)

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

The expected result is 
`Hello, TensorFlow!`
But I get `b'Hello, TensorFlow!'`

Note that the result differ in that `b` is prepended and ouput itself is in single qoutes.

Is there something that I am missing? I had earlier done the same example on Windows (Anaconda) and got same result. I installed only the CPU one.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Python3. The answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal .